# Array re-order keeping current value in same index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array -

```
Array
    (
        [1] => 10890.000
        [2] => 3751.000
        [0] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 0
    )
```

how can i re-order this keeping the current values under the same index. such as following-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 10890.000
    [2] => 3751.000
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
)
```

i already tried array_values() but it does not return expected output

Comment: You want to sort the keys and keep the associations. The function you are looking for is [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is exactly i was looking for..